# Objective-C - how to init enum with NSInteger?

Tags: objective-c

I'm working on an application and my problem started when i tried to encode a model that has an enum property using `NSCoding`. So i had the idea to convert it to the rawValue and the way back. I looked around a bit and came around the macro `NS_ENUM`, so my code looks like this:

```c
typedef NS_ENUM(NSInteger, SectionType) {
    SectionTypeText = 0,
    SectionTypeVideo = 1,
    SectionTypeLink = 2,
    SectionTypeFile = 3,
    SectionTypeQuiz = 4,
    SectionTypeAudio = 5,
    SectionTypeGame = 6,
    SectionTypeHomework = 7
};
```

But i could find no possible way to convert these to the associated value and the way back. How could i do it? There is a better approach than the NS_ENUM macro?

Comment: Your question isn't clear. If the issue is about `NSCoding`, just treat it as a `NSInteger` property for the encode/decode.

Comment: it just _is_ an NSInteger you dont need to cast or do anything, just assign `SectionType s = 5;` `if (s == SectionTypeAudio)` etc...

Comment: if you need it to work for NSKeyValueCoding then you will wrap them in NSNumbers, maybe using the literal syntax if you like... [dict setObject:@(SectionTypeHomework) forKey:@"somekey"]... if you are using just NSCoding then there have been a few iterations of that protocol

Answer (score 16, accepted):

My Objective-C is a bit rusty, but I think I would just cast it:

```
   SectionType type = (SectionType) 2;
```

Back works the same:

```
   int typeNumber = type;
```

Comment: yeah it is freely convertible you dont even need to cast it

Comment: Here ya go. Indeed I remember it to be just syntactic sugar over the base type of the enum.